# How to deploy Sveltekit app with Node adapter and Apache reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, apache, svelte, sveltekit

I created a new Sveltekit app using [adapter-node](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node)

I called

- npm run build
- Copied the directory `./buid`, package.json, package-lock.json, `./node_modules` into a different directory `foo`
- Inside `foo` I call

> HOST=127.0.0.1 PORT=5137 ORIGIN=http://127.0.0.1:5137 node build

and when I try to open it inside the browser everything works as expected. Now I want to move the directory `foo` onto an external virtual machine. This virtual machine is using Polarion ( Siemens ) with Apache, so Apache would have to act as a reverse proxy.

After starting the application in the external VM I added the following to the Apache configuration

```
ProxyPass         /node  http://localhost:5137/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /node  http://localhost:5137/
```

Inside Polarion I'm trying to embed the Sveltekit app with this HTML code

```
<iframe src="/node"></iframe>
```

and it seems it's able to reply with HTML code but it can't send the JS files

[image]

I think it's looking for an `_app` directory inside the root directory of the Apache server but I guess it should look for `/node/_app`?

Do you know what's wrong or missing here?

Comment: I have not used Apache for the last 15 years (and I feel sorry for you), but there shouldn't be anything special with Apache reverse proxy than any other SvelteKit reverse proxy or generic reverse proxy. [If it is any helpful here is an example for Caddy](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/proxy-server/blob/195510dbfdc7c7da4ab876e6fe77116d706819c5/Caddyfile#L59).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set [`paths.base` in the config](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#paths) accordingly, in this case presumably to `/node`.

> A root-relative path that must start, but not end with `/` (e.g. `/base-path`), unless it is the empty string. This specifies where your app is served from and allows the app to live on a non-root path.
> [...]